# PhilJay / MPAndroidChart Chart Freezes UI

Tags: android, mvvm, mpandroidchart, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to plot data of Covid-19 using line chart showing a datewise trend. I am trying to implement this using the MVVM pattern. The code mostly works fine but the UI freezes when I try to filter on USA. I suspect the reason is high rendering time for the charts.

Here is the code in the fragment:

```
homeViewModel.confirmeddataSetLive.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

        fragmentHomeBinding.confirmedChart.invalidate()
        fragmentHomeBinding.confirmedChart.refreshDrawableState()
        if (fragmentHomeBinding.confirmedChart.data == null
            || fragmentHomeBinding.confirmedChart.data.getDataSetCount() == 0
        ) {

            fragmentHomeBinding.confirmedChart.data = LineData(it)


        } else {
            val set1 =
                fragmentHomeBinding.confirmedChart.data.getDataSetByIndex(0) as LineDataSet
            set1.setValues(it.values)
            set1.notifyDataSetChanged()
            fragmentHomeBinding.confirmedChart.data.notifyDataChanged()
            fragmentHomeBinding.confirmedChart.notifyDataSetChanged()

        }


    })
```

This is the code for the viewmodel:

```
private val confirmedLiveData=MutableLiveData<LineDataSet>()
val confirmeddataSetLive:LiveData<LineDataSet>
    get() = confirmedLiveData


 fun setDataToCharts(countryItemList: List<CountryDataItem>){
    if(countryItemList.isNotEmpty()) {
        val firstEntryTimestamp = convertStringToTimestamp(countryItemList[0].Date
        val confirmedValues: ArrayList<Entry> = ArrayList()
        for (i in countryItemList) {
            val confirmedDate = i.Date
            val a = convertStringToTimestamp(confirmedDate)
            val confirmedCountOnDate = i.Confirmed
            val confirmedWorldEntry = Entry(a!!.toFloat(), confirmedCountOnDate.toFloat())
            confirmedValues.add(confirmedWorldEntry)
        }
        val confirmeddataSet = LineDataSet(confirmedValues as List<Entry>?, "Confirmed Cases")   
        viewModelScope.launch {
            showChartonUI(confirmeddataSet)
        }
    }


}

private suspend fun showChartonUI(
    confirmedData: LineDataSet,

) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        confirmedLiveData.postValue(confirmedData)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me that I was performing operations like these right after setting the dataset:

```kotlin
setVisibleXRangeMaximum(...)
centerViewTo(xChartMax, 0f, YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT)
```

I solved it by doing:

```kotlin
chart.post {
    setVisibleXRangeMaximum(...)
    centerViewTo(xChartMax, 0f, YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT)
}
```

I hope I help you out.